# consuming a soap l web service in iphone

Tags: iphone

I am calling the saop web service from the iPhone app. The soap response is a byte []. How can I parse it in the iPhone and display the data in text view? Please help me out.

Comment: Hi, which api did you use to call soap service? I am very new to iphoe and need to call a soap service

Answer (score 0):

you have to parse that data friend using nsxmlparserdelegate.

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *) namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {          }          

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{              }

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{          }

-(void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser{        }
```